# Proc datasets modify several datasets in single step

Tags: dataset, sas

I am using the following to remove labels from a dataset:

```
proc datasets lib=my_lib memtype=data nolist ;
   modify my_data_1 ; 
     attrib _all_ label=' '; 
run;
quit;
```

I would like to do this for several datasets, my_data_1,...,my_data_n. Using the following returns an error (expecting ; , /):

```
proc datasets lib=my_lib memtype=data nolist ;
   modify my_data_1 my_data_2 my_data_3 ;         * and so on ... *;
     attrib _all_ label=' '; 
run;
quit;
```

I was wondering if there was a way to apply exceptions to the following:

```
proc datasets lib=my_lib memtype=data nolist ;
   modify _all_ ;        
   attrib _all_ label=' '; 
run;
quit;
```

The datasets I want to modify being in the majority, this would be more efficient.

Comment: Would writing a macro do loop help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More simple method is to use copy and select, such as:

```
proc datasets ;
copy in=sashelp out=work;
select cars baseball;
attrib _all_ label=' ';
run;
```

Comment: Is it possible to copy into the same library using this method?

Comment: Yes, it is. If I got the syntax right `proc datasets lib=my_lib;
copy;
select my_data_: ; 
attrib _all_ label=' ';
run;` The colon is a wild card.

Comment: This is better than my answer for small datasets. For large datasets, it is too time consuming, as you don't just edit the metadata of the dataset, you copy the complete content.

Answer (score 1):

**Build the datasets** assigning labels to both the datasets and the variable(s) on them;

```
options mprint;
%macro createThem;
    %do i = 1 %to 3;
        data my_data_&i. (label="Set &i.");
            label j="Set &i.";
            do j = 1 to &i;
                output;
            end;
        run;
    %end;
%mend;
%createThem;
```

**Proof this succeded**;

```
proc sql;
    select memname, memlabel from sashelp.vtable 
    where libname='WORK' and memname like 'MY_DATA%'; 
    select memname, name, label from sashelp.vcolumn 
    where libname='WORK' and memname like 'MY_DATA%'; 
run;
```

**Write a macro to remove labels from one dataset**;

```
%macro eraseLabel(data);
    proc datasets lib=WORK memtype=data nolist ;
        modify &data. (label=' ');  ** Remove label form dataset **;
            attrib _all_ label=' '; ** Remove label form variable(s) **;
    run;
    quit;
%mend;
```

**Apply this macro to the datasets involved**;

```
data _null_;
    set sashelp.vtable;
    where libname='WORK' and memname like 'MY_DATA%';
    call execute('%eraseLabel('||memname||')');
run;
```

**Proof this succeded**;

```
proc sql;
    select memname, memlabel from sashelp.vtable 
    where libname='WORK' and memname like 'MY_DATA%';
    select memname, name, label from sashelp.vcolumn 
    where libname='WORK' and memname like 'MY_DATA%';  
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach here is to construct a single call to `proc datasets` which will do everything in one go, using multiple `run;` groups within the proc. The goal is to construct something like this:

```
data example1 example2;
    set sashelp.class;
    label sex = 'example label';
run;

proc datasets lib = work nolist;
    modify example1;
    attrib _all_ label = '';
    run;
    modify example2;
    attrib _all_ label = '';
    run;    
quit;
```

This is possible via a fairly straightforward macro loop, or a data step with call execute, e.g.

```
data _null_;
    set sashelp.vtable end = eof;
    where libname = 'WORK' and memtype = 'DATA' and memname eq: 'EXAMPLE';
    if _n_ = 1  then call execute('proc datasets lib = work nolist nodetails;');    
                     call execute(catx(' ','modify',memname,'; attrib _all_ label = ""; run;'));
    if eof      then call execute('quit;');
run;
```